# Which has better performance Message<String> or Message<byte[]>

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using spring Cloud stream Functional Model
If someone can help understanding which has better performance
Function<Message, Message>
or
Function<Message, Message>
OR
Function<Message<byte[]>, Message<byte[]>>

Comment: Sorry I mean Function<Message<JsonNode>, Message<JsonNode>>

Comment: or Function<Message<String>, Message<String>>